# How to include JavaScript on a website through a Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

How is it possible to execute JavaScript code on a specific page through a Firefox addon. I know I can use Greasemonkey but since I'm porting one of my Chrome extension, I want it to have the exact same features. So my question is, is it possible to execute JavaScript through a Firefox addon as if that JavaScript was executed in the page itself.

I was able to work it out somehow but every time I open a new tab, it gets executed in that tab again. Someone please help me fix this problem. I also want to use jQuery with this.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want an extension that gives you a REPL environment using variables defined on a page, or you want to write your extension that is able to use variables defined on a page. If the latter, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages

Answer (score 1):

I use firebug, and go through the console to manually execute JS functions for testing. Alternatively, if you have to insert a whole JS include file, check out Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks, I also found out that I can do the same with mozIJSSubScriptLoader.